Falco Talon Integration
I am trying to label the pod into suspicious: "true" when one will ssh to a container and remove it upon exit.
I have this rules
- action: Label Pod as Suspicious
  actionner: kubernetes:label
  parameters:
    labels:
      suspicious: "true"  # Changed to string

- rule: Terminal shell in container
  match:
    rules:
      - Terminal shell in container
    output_fields:
      - k8s.ns.name!=kube-system, k8s.ns.name!=falco
  actions:
    - action: Label Pod as Suspicious

When I tried executing ssh and checking the falco logs, it throws this error
... {"container.id":"d1944f4284be",..."evt.type":"execve","k8s.ns.name":null,"k8s.pod.name":null,"proc.cmdline":"sh","proc.exepath":"/usr/bin/dash","proc.name":"sh","proc.pname":null,"proc.tty":34816,"user.loginuid":-1,"user.name":"root","user.uid":0}...

As we can see on the logs it has:
"k8s.ns.name":null and "k8s.pod.name":null
For any context, I am using KinD to deploy my cluster in WSL in Windows.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
